# jQuery .animate() issues, <p> tags are moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery .animate() to change the width of an `<li>` tag. I have text in the `<li>` encased in `<p>` tags so that I can center it, however, when the animation happens the text is moved down by 50% of the `<li>` element, i do not know if the 50% is releated or just coincidence.

my HTML:

```
<div id="about_nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="button_welcome"<p>Welcome</p></li>
                <li id="button_services"><p>Services</p></li>
                <li id="button_naming"><p>Naming</p></li>
                <li id="button_creating"><p>Creating Brands</p></li>
                <li id="button_bizam"><p>Bizam What?</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

my jquery code is:

```
$('#button_welcome').click(function(){
        if($(this)!=previous){ //checks if it was clicked last
            if(previous!=null){ //checks if the previous element exists
                previous.animate({width: 130},150); //resets previous
            }
            $(this).animate({width: 163},150); //animates current
            previous = $(this); //assigns current to previous
            $('#about_content').children().hide(); //resets tabs window
            $('#tab_welcome').show(); //displays correct tab
        }
    });
```

And my css:

```
#about_nav{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:10px;
}
#about_nav ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
}
#about_nav li{
    height:48px;
    width:130px;
    background: #613675; /* old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #613675 0%, #9145B5 50%, #613675 100%); /* firefox */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#613675), color-stop(50%,#9145B5), color-stop(100%,#613675)); /* webkit */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#613675', endColorstr='#613675',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #613675 0%,#9145B5 50%,#613675 100%); /* opera */

    text-align:middle;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px 4px;
    bottom-right-border-radius: 6px 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px 4px;
    top-right-border-radius: 6px 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px 3px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px 3px #444;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px 3px #444;
}
#about_nav li p{
    padding-top:19px;
    padding-bottom:19px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Also, my comparison of `$(this)!=previous` does not seem to work.

So, how can i stop my text moving and keep it centered in the `<li>` and can you help my with my comparison?

Cheers,

Fraser

Comment: `text-align:middle;` should be `text-align: center;`.

Comment: Also, you have an unclosed <li> open tag for #button_welcome. This is probably a big deal.

Comment: Your first `<li` is missing the ending `>`.  is that just a typo in the posted code?

Comment: yeh, i saw that, its not supposed to be there anyways.

Comment: @rockerest,@Joel, whoops thanks for spotting that

Comment: methinks its just a bug, i changed the `<p>` tags to `<div>` and it functions fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P tags are rendered inline, whereas divs are rendered as blocks. Try settings the style of the p tags to display:block; and it should work.

Comment: no it did not, but that sounds like it could be a fix for similar examples, i have then as `<div>` now anyway

Answer (score 1):

First: close this li tag as others have said above.

```
<li id="button_welcome"><p>Welcome</p></li>
```

Second: change your p css to this.

```
#about_nav li p{
padding: 0;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
height: 100%;
padding-top: 15px; /* change this to adjust height of the p tag */
text-align: right;
}
```

Also, with the code given you are not defining 'previous'. I would need to see the rest of your code to see why that is not working.

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nXgSa/

Answer (score 0):

**One line easy fix:**

```
$('#myDiv > p').css('display','block');
```

Also, I noticed in your example you put :

```
<li id="button_welcome"<p>Welcome</p></li>
```

You might have also forgot to close your < li > tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Ultimate fix :**

Looking at the element in the development tools during the animation, it turns out that jQuery apply a style `overflow: hidden;` to the element during the whole transformation.

To fix this, just add the `overflow: visible` property to your `.animate()` function :

```
if(previous!=null) { //checks if the previous element exists
  previous.animate({
    overflow: 'visible', 
    width: 130
  }, 150);
}

$(this).animate({
  overflow: 'visible', 
  width: 163
}, 150); //animates current
```

Here is the JSFiddle to test that the `<p>` tags are not going down anymore : http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/28fmw4vy/1/